# How to load fixtures in a mock object in rails for tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a gem that should take its data from the web but when I'm in test, I want to use a mock object. I want to be able to load data in the mock object using rails fixtures. The mock objects are [here](http://github.com/dsimard/spreedly-gem/blob/eadfbf4afa1d3fb3eae4006bab60a7f320717401/lib/spreedly/mock.rb).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast forward 4 years and there is a gem for this now.

[webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock).  the gem basically shuts down al outgoing api calls and then plops a bunch of code in the error response for you to paste. From there, you adjust it to whatever the desired code's needs are for that response.

Answer (score -1):

> If you have any questions or requests,
>   email us at support@spreedly.com.

It's a commercial site that makes money off subscriptions. They should be more than willing to provide you with the help you need.